# UIScroll View not showing UICollection view as subview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uicollectionview, constraints

```
 CGFloat h = [self getCollectionViewHeight];

NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"WPTableViewWidth"       : @(self.frame.size.width/3),
                @"verticalMargin"         : @(verticalMargin),
                @"intranetHeight"         :@(h),
                @"imageGalleryHeight"     :@([_imageGallery GetHeight]),
                @"nonimageGalleryHeight"  :@([_nonimageGallery GetHeight]),
                @"commentHeight"          :@(0)};
```

Basically I am adding a UICollectionView as subview on ScrollVIew . When I am setting constraints I am using a Metrics as above. I am stuck in here as , when I directly hardcode a value in place of "h" here, the collection view is visible. If i do 
CGFloat h = 500; //Some random value
Collection view is visible.
But if I calculate or get height from contentSize of Collection view and assign it to "h" and pass to metrics. The collection view is not visible.
In short direct value passed displays collection view but when derived from some superviews or UICollectionview.contentview.height, it doesnt display Collection view.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, that `[self getCollectionViewHeight]` returns `0`? (Just put a breakpoint at the line you are creating the `metrics` `NSDictionary` and take a look at the value of `h`.) If this the case, I suggest you are initialising `metrics` at a wrong point in code (maybe in `init` method of the view controller?). If so, just move your 'metrics creation code' into `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller - which is the point after `UIView` sizes have been already calculated.